# what is the nature of force by magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, charge

we know that every matter is electrical i.e every matter is comprised of charge(Atoms) so we can say that everything is charged . Today i have taught by teacher that Charge is actually force - natural force present in every body so A **charged** body attract or repell other body and **magnet** also attract or repell body present near it - it also attract or repell other magnet like charge. NOW we see that both "charge and magnet" has same effect so what is the nature of force of magnet that it attract or repell other thing ? or what really the force is due to which other magnet is affected ??

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/357119/

Comment: i think I am not at that stage to understand your recommended quiestion because im studying simple concepts and i dont even the ABC  of higher levels

Comment: It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking. Please add further information about the context so that potential answerers will know exactly what the issue here is. Possibly [this old question abotu the difference between electric and magnetic fields](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95815/50583) is related?

Comment: Now it is clear may be @ACuriousMind